# iOS Scope bar without search

Tags: ios, element

Is it possible to use such a scope bar like in the phone app http://d.pr/i/xTGQ
without a Search field? I want to use it as a button, but the UITabBar is too large for that.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just an UISegmentedControl I think. You can create one of those in Interface Builder and use it as usual.

Comment: Perfect! Seems like I just found the wrong name for it. Thanks!